# Understanding apply_filters

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I get the same results with these to lines, so what does `apply_filters` do?

```
Line 1 : echo $instance['title'];

Line 2 : echo apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `apply_filter` creates a global filter hook which can be used dynamically all over the system. Which gives you the ability to filter the content of the `$instance['title']`, means you can over ride the content as well as can modify the content. Here is the example-

```
add_filter( 'widget_title', 'widget_title_to_uppercase', 10, 1);
function widget_title_to_uppercase( $content ){
    $content = strtoupper($content);
    return $content;
}
```

Now all the widget title will be uppercase. So with this filter hook you can filter the `widget_title` from any where the WordPress system. But with the `$instance['title']` it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't written a filter using [`add_filter`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) obviously nothing will happen if you apply filters.

Try this in your `functions.php` as an example:

```
add_filter( 'widget_title', 'wpse236433_invert_string' );

function wpse236433_invert_string ($title) {
  return strrev($title);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`apply_filters()` allows you to **modify** a value using a hook. Let me explain-

**Sample-1**: Consider this code, it'll show **Hello World!**,

```
$str = 'Hello World!';
echo $str;
```

**Sample-2**: The code bellow will show **Hello World!** too, but it will make the string *modifiable*-

```
$str = 'Hello World!';
echo apply_filters( 'modify_str', $str );
```

**Sample-3**: If you use a filter hook (in a plugin or your functions.php file), the code I wrote in Sample-2 will show **HELLO WORLD!**

```
function modify_hello_world( $str ){
    return strtoupper( $str );
}
add_filter( 'modify_str', 'modify_hello_world' );
```

Hope it makes sense.